# Derived equation

Tags: algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about the “Cat in the Hat” problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65137/question-about-the-cat-in-the-hat-problem)

I'm looking at the [Cat in the Hat](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_107) problem. Can anyone explain to me how a simple math logic is used to derive this equation?

```
(N/(N+1))^(M-1) = B/A
```

Comment: You're going to have to give us more info. What is N, M, B and A? This is homework, right?

Comment: The equation is *not* true if A=0 or N=0

Comment: @Jonathan Not a homework,I am done studying and the link has all the information regarding the variables

Comment: @Platinum Azure well it has something to do with algorithms too

Comment: @Jonathan Please use the link by clicking the equation in the description

Comment: you should parenthesize that expression :/

Comment: Check out std::binary_search, in the <algorithm> standard header

Comment: @dario_ramos sure.

Comment: @pcraft: it is protocol on this site to make your questions self-contained, rather than relying on outside links. If you want people to give you answers, you will have to define your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be broken down into two parts:

a. Number of working cats:
We know that inside each cat's hat (that isn't a working cat) there are N smaller cats (all of the same size) and that there is M different sizes of cats. Therefore, there must be N^(M-1) working cats.

But we know that there are B working cats, hence B = N^(M-1).

b. Size of the largest cat:
We know that the size of the working cats is 1 and that if the cat is of size H, then the cat who has it in its hat is of size H*(N+1). Given that there are M different sizes of cats this means the largest cat must be 1 * (N+1)^(M-1).

But we know that the largest cat is of size A, hence A = (N+1)^(M-1).

Now we put these two equations together.

B/A = N^(M-1)/((N+1)^(M-1)) = (N/N+1)^(M-1)

Comment: Thanks at-last for not suggesting edits and stuff and simply answering .